# Zend Framework transactions like Spring Framework

Tags: zend-framework

I have a Spring framework background and if you know a little bit of this you know that you can have a transactional service method, called for example, myStuffTransactional() and this one can have a bunch of DAOs operations and if any of the DAO's operation fails then all  the method myStuffTransactional() will fail and will rollback.

Example:

```
@Transactional
public void myStuffTransactional(){
   dao1.insertSome();
   dao2.deleteSome();
   dao3.updateSome();
}
```

But here i know that if dao3.updateSome() fails then dao1 and doa2 will rollback and my database will remain without change.

Now I have a time using PHP Zend framework, but I can get the same Spring-transactional-behaviour. I have seen a buch of examples like:

```
$db->beginTransaction();
try
{
$db->exec($sqlSentence);
$query = $db->commit();
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
$db->rollBack();
}
```

And this one just works in a model (or DAO) way, I mean, operation for operation. What I need is a method wrapper for a bunch of database operations just like spring framework does.

Anyone knows if this is possible?

Thank you in advance people.

Comment: You might try an ORM/DBAL like [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/) or [Propel](http://www.propelorm.org/) if you are not satisfied with the Zend Framework database tools. However I think it is unlikely you'll find anything similar to the Spring Framework experience in PHP at this time.

Comment: Then how big companies using Zend face this issue?

Comment: They use an ORM/DBAL like Doctrine or Propel or they do the work to write their own abstraction layer. The tools to do what Spring Framework does are readily available, but that implementation is theirs and even SF uses a number of different tools to achieve their own interpretation of an ORM/DBAL.